# SCORM version in moodle

Tags: moodle, scorm

i want to know..
how can i know SCORM version that are my company use?
and I want to know the latest version of SCORM..
Because i read moodle docs but dont know how to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to determine which version of SCORM some content is using, the easiest way is to look at the contents of the imsmanifest.xml file.

There are some templates for what the manifest files should look like for different versions [here](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/xml-schema-definition-files/). You can also probably tell by looking at which set of XSD files are included with the package as those will vary between SCORM versions as well.

A simpler way is to import the course into the freely available [SCORM Cloud](http://cloud.scorm.com/). Launch the course from the "SCORM Test Track Sandbox" section and then click on "View Debug". Expand the Activity Data tree until you see the "Course Information" node and it will tell you which learning standard the course is using.

[image]

If you are trying to determine which version of SCORM your LMS supports, the easiest way is to just ask your vendor. You can also just try importing packages of various versions to see what works. Sample content from every version is available [here](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/). If you are referring to Moodle, I know that they have support for SCORM 1.2 and very basic support for some of SCORM 2004. If you need full SCORM 2004 support in Moodle, look [here](http://scorm.com/moodle).